# Regex starting at the next character of a match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I noticed that in regex if you use  a capturing group and you try to use * to match multiple parts of the string will always start matching at the end of the last match for example: "00000"
If I use (000)* it will only match the first "000" (range 0-2)inclusive , I want it to match range(0-2),(1,3),(2,4) inclusive.
[Image Example Of Match Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fzQv.png)
https://regexr.com/3anj3

Any Ideas on how to do this or if it is at all possible:

Thank you,

Comment: You need overlapping matches, use `(?=(000))`

Comment: Oh thank you, I used (0)*(?=(00)) and that work, i guess look ahead can be used to match the next two characters as regex loops through looking for group 1 (0)* really appreciate the help :).